# Avoiding the need to call ProcessMessages

Tags: delphi, controls, component-design

I've got a component I created that embeds a hardware-accelerated renderer in a TWinControl so you can place it on a form.  It works pretty well in most cases, but if I try to resize the control, everything goes blank until the message loop runs and calls the WndProc for the renderer, which is hosted in an external DLL.  This means that I need to call Application.ProcessMessages explicitly after I've resized the control in code, which I know is considered bad practice.

Is there any way to put some logic in the control itself to make it invoke the WndProc in the DLL when I change the control's size, so I won't need to call ProcessMessages to get stuff to render right?

Comment: +1 for wanting to avoid ProcessMessages in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could call `TWinControl.Update` instead, which should just SendMessage a WM_PAINT event, so you aren't handling arbitrary messages.

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution is to call InvalidateRect when you resize.  Windows will then post you a WM_PAINT message.  For reference you should pull Petzold off the shelf and read his chapter on painting.

Comment: What's more, if you system settings are not to re-draw windows whilst resizing then you won't get the WM_PAINT until the re-size operation is complete.